# Warp-sharp script not working in Gimp 2.8

Tags: gimp, sharpening

I have been scanning film and I just got sick of the `Unsharp mask` setting of my scanner software (EPSON Scan). It just makes the grain look *huge and unnatural*, resulting in weird contrast on most images. Trying to find better ways to sharpen my images I decided to try some other options like [smart sharpening](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Smart_Sharpening/) or [warp-sharp](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Smart_Sharpening/warp-sharp.html) on Gimp. The first option seems great but the warp-sharp seems most practical because it implies to just run a script on the image.

I downloaded the warp-sharp script from [here](http://www.home.unix-ag.org/simon/gimp/warp-sharp.scm) and placed it in `C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\share\gimp\2.0\scripts`. I then refreshed the `Script-fu` scripts under the `Filters` bar. I now can find the `Warp sharp` tool under `Filters->Enhance->Warp sharp`.

But whenever I run the script on a picture, I get the following error messages:

[image]

I tried searching about this issue but nothing relevant came up. Or at least I could not find it. How can I make the script work?

Answer (score 2):

### It's most likely a problem with versions

The plugin you downloaded is said to be version 1.5 and though it says (emphasis mine):

> Version 1.5 updated for Gimp 2.2 **and later**

The official [help pages](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-scripting.html) for GIMP scripting says (again, emphasis mine):

> Plugins have been a feature of GIMP for many versions. However, **plugins written for one version of GIMP can hardly ever be used successfully with other versions**. They need to be ported: sometimes this is easy, sometimes not. Many plugins are already available in several versions. Bottom line: before trying to install a plugin, make sure that it is written for your version of GIMP.

**EDIT**: Apparently this is an issue [present for many years](http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=5962).

**UPDATE**: The GIMP team is [revamping the tutorials](https://www.gimp.org/news/2016/05/05/revamping-tutorials/); so while the link to the Warp-sharp tutorial is still there, it's no longer *advertised* in the [tutorials page](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/).

Comment: I am aware of the information that you provide in your answer, but I find it strange that the official GIMP website continues to host a tutorial using this particular script if it no longer works for the current version...

Comment: @jrojasqu GIMP relies on participation from users for both the program itself and keeping the website updated. Perhaps you could contact them to let them know?

Comment: It seems like this has never been brought up to the original script author - who is present on the irc://irc.gimp.org/gimp IRC channel, btw.

Comment: FWIW, I sent him an email but hasn't answered. @MichaelSchumacher do you know his IRC nick? Or did you happen to tell him about this?

Answer (score 1):

This may be way old, but I ran into the same issue and some google fu found this that may be a newer, updated version of the warp-sharpen script (although no apparent credit to Simon Budig who seems to have written it originally) but it does have the same description:

https://www.gimphelp.org/sharpness_warp-sharp.html

I did test it on 2.10.xx and it does indeed run.